# Android: Seek video frame by frame onSeekbar changed

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar

I used video view and seek bar in my project, here is the current code when seek bar changed

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {

            if (fromUser) {
                // this is when actually seekbar has been seeked to a new
                // position
                videoView.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is: when draw seekbar the video seekto not smooth, it's skip frame.

For example:

Point 1 to point 2:

Duration: 1 second

Frames: 3

If play video by videoView.start() it's OK, but if draw seekbar from point 1 to point 2 it's skiped frame 2.

Answer (score 0):

When encoding a video stream, there will usually be something called the I frame (I-Picture) or the Key frame, it means that this frame has lot of information and can be used to decode a frame in its entirety. To reduce the amount of space all the frames are not encoded as key frames instead they are encoded as P (Predicted) frames or predicted frames, meaning you can decode a P frame with the help from the key frame.

So during the seek operation, in this case the seeking is done to the closest key frame for a given time duration. For example if the user seeks to 40 seconds and the closest key frame is at 35th sec then seeking is done to the 35th sec and not to the 40th second.

You can still try the following to see if it works. Distance between to I pictures is usually 0.5 seconds. So instead of seeking per millisecs, try with secs to jump directly to an I picture.

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {

        if (fromUser) {
            // this is when actually seekbar has been seeked to a new
            // position
            videoView.seekTo(progressx1000);
        }
    }
enter code here
```

---

Try to call it in onStopTrackingTouch() like this:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
     videoView.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
}
```

This is how I do it in my projects.

Comment: @Nicky What problem are you facing , using this solution? Should work!

Comment: Please see this video [link](https://youtu.be/mAnfzJlfmSM) (Case seekTo onProgressChanged). 
As you can see, it's lagging when I dragging the seekBar. And if I put seekTo onStopTrackingTouch, it's only seekTo when I stop dragging. 
Thanks

Comment: Still didn't work, my issue is video.seekTo() skip frame, so when slide the seek bar video preview not smooth.

Comment: This will not work, it will always seek to the key frame. Mediacodec is the only native way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

The VideoViewer seekTo() function is a bit limited and assumes you want to snap back to the key frame. The MediaPlayer, however, allows you to override that choice:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(time, MediaPlayer.SEEK_CLOSEST);
```

Other values include: SEEK_PREVIOUS_SYNC, SEEK_NEXT_SYNC, SEEK_CLOSEST_SYNC.

If you don't already have an instance of the MediaPlayer, you can access it in the onPreparedListener of the VideoViewer, for example.

For details on MediaPlayer's seekTo, see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(long,%20int)).